# Showing custom error message on web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have created an ASP.NET Web API which calls a java web server to retrieve data. When the java web server is down, i want the Web API to show an error message: `{"ErrorMessage:" Server is down}` What are the codes that i should add to achieve the custom error message to be shown on the browser?

Here are my codes:

**RestfulClient.cs**

```
public class RestfulClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static RestfulClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> addition(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {

        try
        {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //What do i have to code here?
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**AdditionController.cs**

```
public class Temp
{
    public string firstNumber { get; set; }
    public string secondNumber { get; set; }
    public string sum { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionController : ApiController
{
    private RestfulClient restfulClient = new RestfulClient();
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        var result = await restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temp>(result);
        return Json(resultDTO);
    }
}
```

Someone please do help me, thank you so much.

Comment: A `try/catch`...

Answer (score 0):

If you catch an exception of type `Exception` and then decide the server you called is down, that would not be true. Something may go wrong within your own code before you call the other service or after the other service has returned successfully. Therefore, you need to be careful how you make that decision.

Having said that it is still hard to say when you can make that decision with confidence: Is the calling service returning the correct message etc.

Anyhow, you can do something similar to this:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure)
    {
        // To use these 2 commented out returns, you need to change 
        // your method's return type to Task<IHttpActionResult>
        // return Content(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, "Unavilable.");
        // return StatusCode(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
        return "Unavailable"
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // You could be here because something went wrong in your server,
    // or the server you called which was not caught by the catch above
    // because it was not WebException. Make sure to give it some 
    // thought.
    // You need to change 
    // your method's return type to Task<IHttpActionResult> or 
    // just return a string.
    return StatusCode(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

Comment: If i change the method to Task<IHttpActionResult> i can return Ok(response) right? What should i change the `var endpoint` part to?

Comment: I think i need it to be Task<string> as `var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);` this line of code is important when i retrieve the data from java web service

Comment: Why is there so many 'returns' Sorry please do guide me along i'm quite new to this

Comment: @SushaNaidu You do not need to change the `var endpoint` to anything. There are many returns because I wanted to show you that you have those options. Just use one of them. And you did the right thing by changing it to `Task<IHttpActionResult>`. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: When i change it to `Task<IHttpActionResult>` i get 2 errors. I am getting a red line under `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and the error states `Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult`

Comment: Another error i am getting is from the AdditionController.cs class. I am getting a red line under (result) error stating `Cannot convert from System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult to string`